# Converting VB6 code snippet to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am having a hard time converting this snippet to VB.NET

```
Function DecryptPassword(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sPass As String = s.Trim()

    For i = 1 To Len(sPass)
        If Asc(Mid$(sPass, i, 1)) - 5 < 124 Then

            'this line throws "type char $ does not match declared data type char"
            Mid$(sPass, i, 1) = Chr$(Asc(Mid$(sPass, i, 1)) - 5) 

        Else
            Mid$(sPass, i, 1) = Mid$(sPass, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    DecryptPassword = UCase(sPass)  ' Convert UserPassword to UpperCase
End Function
```

It works well in VB6 but throws error when i VB.Net..

Comment: Did you try Visual Studio's upgrade wizard?

Comment: Have you tried w/o the non-$ versions of mid?

Comment: @hydroparadise - The upgrade wizard is not available in VS2010 onwards so depends on which version the OP has

Comment: Good to know.  I do have VB.NET 2010 Express and noticed it *didn't* have it.  Just thought it was not included in the Express version.

Comment: vb2008 is the last to include the upgrade wizard as far as I know. The express version of this can still be downloaded I think. I think you have to do a little jiggery pokery to register it though.

Answer (score 5):

Try this version:

```
Function DecryptPassword(ByVal s As String) As String

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
        Return String.Empty
    End If

    Dim sbPass As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s.Length)

    For Each oCharacter As Char In s.Trim
        If Asc(oCharacter) - 5 < 124 Then
            sbPass.Append(Convert.ToChar(Asc(oCharacter) - 5))
        Else
            sbPass.Append(oCharacter)
        End If
    Next
    Return sbPass.ToString.ToUpper
End Function
```

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Well, it has `Return`, `For Each`, and `StringBuilder`, but it fails at run time because the string builder is empty. Capacity set in the constructor is not same as the text length stored, which is `0`. Should use `sbPass.Append` instead of the indexer.

Comment: Good point! Creating the StringBuilder with `s.Length` and using `Append()` together is the way to go.

Comment: Good catch GSerg: The code was iteratively rewritten to get to this point and I forgot to include append in the final version. I have fixed the answer and included an initial check for s isnullorempty so that we don't get an exception when initializing stringbuilder.

Comment: @competent_tech One more iteration required. `sbPass.Append(wIndex) = oCharacter` => `sbPass.Append(oCharacter)`. Same above.

Comment: Good gravy mabeline. I really should pay more attention to what I am doing sometimes. This has been fixed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work (just removed the "$" like Booji Boy wrote).

```
Function DecryptPassword(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sPass As String = s.Trim()

    For i = 1 To Len(sPass)
        If Asc(Mid(sPass, i, 1)) - 5 < 124 Then
            Mid(sPass, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(sPass, i, 1)) - 5)
        Else
            Mid(sPass, i, 1) = Mid(sPass, i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    DecryptPassword = UCase(sPass)  ' Convert UserPassword to UpperCase 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it, a linq approach.

```
Function DecryptPassword(ByVal s As String) As String
    Return s.Aggregate(Of String)(String.Empty, Function(acc, c) acc & Char.ToUpper(If(Asc(c) - 5 < 124, Convert.ToChar(Asc(c) - 5), c)))
End Function
```

Or

```
Function DecryptPassword(ByVal s As String) As String
    Return New String((From c In s Select Char.ToUpper(If(Asc(c) - 5 < 124, Convert.ToChar(Asc(c) - 5), c))).ToArray)
End Function
```